# Bond option price under hull-white model with different settlement and expiration dates

Tags: options, bond, hullwhite, expiration, settlement

I am aware of bond option (lets say, call option) price formula under Hull-White model, for example, here -
https://www.applied-financial-mathematics.de/sites/default/files/Teaching/InterestRateModellingWS20/IRModellingLecture_Part4.pdf

I wanted to know if there is a reference which gives the formula when we have $$t_s > t_e$$. That is, when settlement date of the option is greater than the expiry date. I have calculated the formula myself but I wanted to check my calculations against a standard reference. Can somebody please help me out here?